# Tesseract 4.0 OCR results inconsistent

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, text-processing

We are trying to perform ocr on image with 2 characters and tesseract command returns incorrect output.

[image: Tesseract processed image]

Clearly expected result should be TV but we are getting AY.

[image: Another tesseract processed image]

Result should have been S7 Ep7, but we are getting [Sa aes]. Which as you can see is not even close.

Tesseract processed images look quite clear and it should be working on them but getting such inconsistent results on clear images is confusing.

Any ideas on how we can achieve better result.

For a similar image we start getting correct result. Example.
[Correct result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8N91.png)

As you can see these are similar images with just few pixels up and down. But they give totally different results.

Comment: Inconsistent results means that you are getting different output from the same image. Is this the case?

Comment: @Dmitrii,Thanks for reply. Yes, We get different results for same image with few pixels up and down. If we just pass S7 Ep7 portion we some time get correct result but when we increase the size or length it starts giving inconsistent results.  In case of TV image if we increase the pixels of image we start getting [ae] as the result. FYI these images are being cropped from larger 4K image.